# Google Books library dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-books

I would like to load the google books library only when the user perform a specific action (pressing a button for example).

The following code does not work (I cannot create a DefaultViewer for example):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>
  Click me
</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/books/jsapi.js"></script>

<script>
function hello() {
  alert("hello");
}

$('button').click(function() {
  google.books.load();
  google.books.setOnLoadCallback(hello);
})
</script>
```

whereas the non-dynamic version works without problem :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/books/jsapi.js"></script>

<script>
function hello() {
  alert("hello");
}

google.books.load();
google.books.setOnLoadCallback(hello);
</script>
```

Can somebody explain to me why ?

Also, for me, [the first example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/books/examples/linkSingleBook) from the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/dynamic-links#code-samples) is not working. Maybe it is related.

Thanks in advance.